# SL5 In Browser WebBrowser Control error "Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered" when re-navigating to another PDF

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, pdf, iis-7.5, silverlight-5.0

Finally bit the bullet and replaced my hack for displaying PDF content inside a silverlight app with a proper SL5 Trusted In-Browser WebBrowser that navigates to a **.pdf**.

When i try to **RE**-navigate the WebBrowser **to another PDF** I am seeing the error **"Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100)"**

**This only happens when I deploy to IIS (localhost IIS *and* another server IIS 7.5) ... NOT while running in VS2010.**

***Details:***

UI is extremely simple. 1 Grid w/ 2 columns:

Column 1    Column2
========    ====================================================================
Treeview    `<WebBrowser x:Name="ContentWebBrowser" Grid.Column="1"></WebBrowser>`

When user selects an item in the treeview, I simply call:

```
Uri serverUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/",
Application.Current.Host.Source.DnsSafeHost,
Application.Current.Host.Source.Port));

var relative= "/Content/x/y/z.pdf"; //This is dynamiclly pulled from Treeview, EDITED FOR SO
Uri relativeUri = new Uri(relative, UriKind.Relative);

ContentWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(serverUri, relativeUri));
```

With Cassini running silverlight both w/ and w/o debugger via VS2010 i can Select item after item in my list view and my WebBrowser will "re-navigate" calling this same code above.
BUT, once i deploy to my local iis, any time i end up calling Navigate for the 2nd time I am getting this error:

```
System.Exception: Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040100)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.WebBrowser_Navigate(DependencyObject obj, Uri source)
   at System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.Navigate(Uri source)
   at SystemUtilities.Views.WebContentListView.TreeViewItem_Selected(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

**Other oddities**: Sometimes i can "re-navigate" 3 or 4 times before i see this exception. Sometimes when i load another page in my SL application this error gets thrown.  Happens whether PDF is cached or not cached when I load it into the WebBrowser.  If i display standard html or an image instead of a PDF this does not happen.

**Edit**: I added logic to check to make sure LoadCompleted event fires before i try to re-navigate the WebBrowser but it does not seem to matter. (not 100% sure but i think that it ignores the fact that the PDF might still be loading and just signals that the DOM is ready).  Although, even if I want a long time (30 seconds) after it looks like the 1st pdf is done loading, i still get the error.

Any suggestions?

---

**New** I posted my sample on skydrive.. check out the readme in order to repro!: http://sdrv.ms/JSn1KB

Comment: Sample now up on skydrive! http://sdrv.ms/JSn1KB

Comment: Since this happens only in IIS, perhaps it is a permissions problem. Have you figured it out yet? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @NoOne Never have it resolved, i almost asked Pete Brown at the Build conf but i spared him the pain (myself the embarrassment).  I also offered a bounty and no one answered.  Solution to my problem was drop Silverlight and move to HTML5